# Receiving "error: no such file or directory, open" when passing a remote file to libreoffice-convert library in a Node.js app

Tags: node.js, libreoffice

I'm currently building a Node.js application that will eventually be used to convert certain file formats into other formats. Most of the work is being done by the [libreoffice-convert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libreoffice-convert) library.

I am able to do file conversions without any issues when passing a local file path to the library but it doesn't seem to be working when I grab the contents of a remote file via `request()` and pass the received body to libreoffice-convert.

This is the relevant code I have right now:

```
request(fileUrl, {encoding: 'binary'}, function(error, response, body) {
    const ext = '.html';

    libre.convert(body, ext, undefined, (err, done) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Error converting file: ${err}`);
        res.sendStatus(500);
      } else {
        console.log(done);
      }
    });

  });
```

I can see that when I run this, libreoffice starts the conversion but eventually, I'm getting this error:
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/j9/z_z85kh5501dbslrg53mpjsw0000gn/T/libreofficeConvert_-6529-x08o2o3peLMh/source..html`

The example libreoffice-convert code gets the local file using `fs.readFileSync()` but given that I want to get my contents from a remote file, I'm passing the `body` received in the `request()` call.

To be sure that `body` has the correct contents, I compared the result I receive from `fs.readFileSync()` to the result I receive from `request()` when calling for the same exact file locally and remotely. There didn't seem to be any differences at all.

Am I missing something or it's a matter that the libreoffice-convert library or libreoffice itself doesn't support this?

Answer (score 3):

libreoffice-convert is dependent on some linux package, i.e. libreoffice-writer. `apt install libreoffice-writer` will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks ! That should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: Also LibreOffice requires a more specifically soffice. Test if the command "soffice" in your linux.